# show elements of related tables with ng-repeat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, relationships

I am trying to show a column of a related table with ng-repeat, but I can't.

I have 3 tables:

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.time     "hour"
t.integer  "duration"
t.date     "date"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
t.float    "latitude"
t.float    "longitude"
t.string   "formatted_addres"
t.integer  "location_id"
end

create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "event_id"
t.integer  "tag_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "taggings", ["event_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_event_id"
add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name"
```

and I am using ng-repeat to show the events

```
    controller code:    
    app.controller('eventController', ['$http', function($http){
                var store = this;
                store.events = [];

                $http.get('/events.json').success(function(data){
                    store.events = data;
            });
    }]);

    The html code:
    <section ng-repeat="event in eventShow.events | orderBy:'date'">
            <div class="panel panel-default single-event">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>
                        {{event.title}}
                        <em class="pull-right">Created by user: {{event.user_id}}</em>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Description:<br>{{event.description}} <br>
                    <em class="pull-right">{{event.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }} - {{event.hour | date:"H:mm"}}</em> <br>
                    {{event.duration}} minutes <br>
            {{ event.tags }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Everything works, but when I try tho show the tags on the ng-repeat like {{ event.tags.name }} it doesn't show anything.
In rails works a similar sintaxis, but I see in angular it must be done in a different way. I was searching information about it yesterday and today and I did not find anything. Anybody can help? Thanks!

This is the data of my controller:

```
  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end
```

If I do a binding.pry I can do @events.first.tags and I see al tags of this event, so in ruby code I can do

```
<ul>    
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
       <li><%= event.tags %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

And this is what I can't do with angular {{ event.tags }} the json response that I get from get /events.json is like this

```
    [
  {
    "id": 18,
    "title": "awesome event",
    "description": "incredible description",
    "hour": "2000-01-01T11:12:00.000Z",
    "duration": 12,
    "date": "2015-11-25",
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2015-11-26T11:57:03.433Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-26T11:57:03.433Z",
    "latitude": 42.5767239,
    "longitude": 3.4435419,
    "formatted_addres": "somewhere",
    "location_id": null
  }
]
```

and if I use the debugger, obviously I only see the fields that are in the json with the ng-repat. But I need to list the items in the column of another table ralated like I do in rails.

I'm using:

- Rails 4.2.5
- Ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769)

please be patient with me I'm sill learning angular

Comment: Are you sure that in your response there's a field `name` in `tags` ?

Comment: In ruby I list the related tables doing <ul><% @events.each do |event| %><li><%= event.tag.name %></li> <% end %></ul> because the event is related to tags through taggings, so I think that in angular should be similar but I see I can't do this on angular and I don't find the way to do it.

Comment: Use `console.log` to see what your response looks like

Comment: I used console log, and I only can see the fields of the table events, I can't see the fields of the related tables as tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by change controller code:

```
app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

            $http.get('/events.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.events = data;
        });
}]);
```

Change your html with `events` scope

```
<section ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'date'">
```

for your reference about **[`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)** in `angularjs`

---

**Update:**

**create file** => **`app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder`**

```
json.array! @events do |event|
  json.(event, :id, :title, :description, :hour, :duration, :date, :user_id, :latitude, :longitude, :formatted_addres, :location_id)
  json.tags event.tags
end

# change in controller:

 def index
    @events = Event.all
    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json 
    end
  end
```

Comment: I tryed it but I get "ReferenceError: $scope is not defined" in console. I tryed even inject it with app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$http', function($http){...} but still get the error

Comment: I solved the error, I was not including the $scope on the function(), now it works perfectly, but I still can't list the column of the related table with {{ event.tags }}

Comment: @Alex for that you need to check your `events.json.jbuilder` file

Comment: post your `/events.json` response or check where is your tags are defined?

Comment: The events response is like this:  [{"id":6,"title":"new event","description":"description!","hour":"2000-01-01T11:20:00.000Z","duration":50,"date":"2015-11-24","user_id":1,"created_at":"2015-11-25T19:05:11.053Z","updated_at":"2015-11-25T19:05:11.053Z","latitude":41.3918848,"longitude":2.1806089,"formatted_addres":"arc","location_id":null}]

Comment: And this is my method in the controller that responds: # GET /events
 `# GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end`

Comment: @Alex : create json.builder file and little bit change in controller like http://pastie.org/private/jrgbkjrlry6wl3ju4fmuza

Comment: Thank you, it works now. But now I have to do a nested ng-repeat to list the tag names inside.

Comment: Glad to help you. You can upvote my answer. for `nested ng-repeat` what you want post your requirement also

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind some variable in UI you need to bind it to `$scope` first. So try using `$scope.store` instead var store.

> Inject `$scope` in dependencies.